# looking for a MutiSelect with search

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, multi-select, jquery-select2

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

I am looking for a Multiselect  that adds the selected fields to another box and has a search feature. Something like this. 
http://www.jqueryrain.com/?c6ebuEZT

and https://select2.github.io/examples.html

IT will be so nice if you can help me find something like that.
It will save me alot of time and days because i wont have to write it from scratch ThankYOU!

Comment: Try [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/).

Comment: Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation. If you can't do that yet, try some more of your own work first or searching for more general help;